# Laravel - Dropping foreign key and adding in one migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to drop the foreign key and add the foreign key in one migration but can't get it to work:
I have created the table `contents` with the `foreign key cms_id`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('ct_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('ct_id')->references('id')->on('content_types');
        $table->integer('cms_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('cms_id')->references('id')->on('inventories');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->text('excerpt');
        $table->mediumText('body');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('parent_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is how the inventories table looks like:

```
Schema::create('inventories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('remote_id');
    $table->integer('local_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('local_type');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And after failing to drop it and to create a new foreign key, I have deleted all the tables in the DB, and have tried to run all the migrations again with the new one as well, which holds this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('inventories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('remote_id')->unsigned()->change();
    });

    Schema::table('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('contents_cms_id_foreign');
        $table->foreign('cms_id')->references('remote_id')->on('inventories');
    });

    Schema::table('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('files_cms_id_foreign');
        $table->foreign('cms_id')->references('remote_id')->on('inventories');
    });
}
```

But,I get:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL     : alter table `contents` add constraint
>   `contents_cms_id_foreign` foreign k     ey (`cms_id`) references
>   `inventories` (`remote_id`))
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

If, I first run all the migrations where I create all the tables, and then after that run the new migration where I change the foreign keys, I get this error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP
>   'content     s_cms_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists (SQL:
>   alter table `contents` drop foreign key
>   `contents_cms_id_foreign`)
>
> ```
>                                                                               [PDOException]
> ```
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP
>   'content     s_cms_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists

I have even tried to just delete all the tables in the DB, and only edit the files that I already have by just changing, without new migrations:

```
    $table->integer('ct_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('ct_id')->references('remote_id')->on('content_types');
    $table->integer('cms_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('cms_id')->references('remote_id')->on('inventories');
```

And, also in the inventories table:

```
$table->integer('remote_id')->unsigned();
```

But, even then it won't work, and I get:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL     : alter table `contents` add constraint
>   `contents_cms_id_foreign` foreign k     ey (`cms_id`) references
>   `inventories` (`remote_id`))
>
> ```
>                                                                          [PDOException]
> ```
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

So, I have checked all of the usual suspects that I have come across on the internet, I have even added `$table->engine = 'InnoDB'`; to to the tables `inventories`, `contents` and `files`, I have made sure to first create `tables` and then add `foreign keys`, as well as checked if the columns have the same `data type`, not sure what to do else?

Comment: if the value of foreign key column exist in any other tables related to that column so that time you cane alter the foreign key, first you need to remove that value

Comment: `remote_id` is it a primary key in the `inventories` table?

Comment: I have added the inventories table as well to the question, and no remote_id is not primary key

Comment: is there any data in you contents table?

Comment: no, I have dropped all the tables and creating everything all over with migrations, but I wan't to have the separate migration files for it, so that the others can just run php artisan migrate

Comment: Add `->unsigned()` to `remote_id` => `$table->integer('remote_id')->unsigned();` and see if it work ?!

Comment: @Maraboc no, that doesn't help

Comment: Try this time with the unique constraint first `$table->integer('remote_id')->unsigned()->unique();` !

Comment: It didn't help unfortunately

Comment: Instead of ``$table->integer('ct_id')->unsigned();`` could you try ``$table->unsignedInteger('ct_id')``?